# Don't update the input values when press button, but in database yes

Tags: php, page-refresh

Hey guys i have a problem updating input data, once I press to refresh load the page but the previous values ​​remain and the database if it is updated. Neither refreshing the page appear the new data, I have to logout and re-enter.

use this

```
function account_profile( array $data ) {
        if ( !empty( $data ) ) {
            $trimmed_data = array_map( 'trim', $data );

            $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data[ 'user_id' ] );
            $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data[ 'first_name' ] );
            $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data[ 'last_name' ] );
            $address = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data[ 'address' ] );
            $city = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data[ 'city' ] );
            $telephone = mysqli_real_escape_string( $this->_con, $trimmed_data[ 'telephone' ] );

            $query = "UPDATE users SET first_name = '$first_name', last_name = '$last_name', address = '$address', city = '$city', telephone = '$telephone' WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
            if ( mysqli_query( $this->_con, $query ) ) {
                mysqli_close( $this->_con );
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception( FIELDS_MISSING );
        }
    }
```

and this to get the values

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Sólo letras" value="<?php
if ( $_POST ) {
    echo $_POST[ 'first_name' ];
} else {
    echo $_SESSION[ 'first_name' ];
}
?>" required>
...
```

thanks for any advice

Comment: Are you doing a new SELECT query on the row when you refresh the page or is displaying already been requested? Also I suggest don't use mysqli_real_escape_string, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure if I understand your question correctly.
but for your code

```
`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Sólo letras" value="<?php
if ( $_POST ) {
    echo $_POST[ 'first_name' ];
} else {
    echo $_SESSION[ 'first_name' ];
}
?>" required>`
```

It is better to to use `if (isset($_POST['first_name']))` to make sure the first_name is not empty when making POST request.

The main problem of your code is that you probably forgot to set the first_name value in your session every time you clicked the button, and that's why you dont see the newest value if you refresh the page because $_SESSION['first_name'] is not updated at all!.

so from my understanding, please try the following code

```
if (isset($_POST['first_name'])){  //First Name changed, so we update it 
   $_SESSION['first_name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
}
echo $_SESSION['first_name'];  //Print data (first_name in this instance)
```

You probably dont need else for this because the old value will always be in the session if you press the button before anyway

Comment: Please check my edit, I have added echo statement to print the data now

Comment: Sorry, the echo statement should be outside the if statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
```

Rather than

```
if ($_POST) {
```